# Example non-trivial Java EE web service implementation?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

My organization is considering switching from an in-house proprietary
application server (and adhoc protocols) to a Java EE 5 / Java EE 6 framework +
web services for new development, and we're trying to get our heads
around how we'd do that.

We're experiencing something of a culture shock; we're comfortable
with emacs/vi, command-line tools, shell scripts and calling libraries;
all the documentation we encounter seems to assume we're using Eclipse,
IDE plugins, ant and/or maven and some huge framework which makes it
hard to even understand what code is executing. I think an example
would help enormously, so my question is:

Is there a modern, non-trivial example Java EE application (or real-world open source application) out there that provides a WS-I style web service interface and ideally also demonstrates using a relational database?

I've found various "hello world" applications and tutorials that
create some sort of web service using a Java EE framework, but never
anything more complicated than a temperature conversion service!

Comment: @Kevin Egham: no answer so commenting: there are a few things for which Eclipse/IntelliJ/whatever's text editors simply don't cut it, so I configured my Emacs to auto-reload on changes.  I switch back and forth IntelliJ/Emacs quite often when working on the same codebase/.java files.  I'm mainly a Java developer yet use command line all the time and wrote custom shell scripts to parse/process .java files (to do things IDE simply cannot do, just as their limited text editor cannot do what Emacs can).  This comment just to say: you're not alone and you won't have to give up everything :)

Comment: @Kevin Egham: you could try Googling for the "Pet Store" demo webapp.  It used to be all the rage years ago and there have been several "new pet stores" and whatnots.

Comment: Is there the possibility of hiring someone who has experience with this stuff? It is very easy to make a complete mess of the new system if you don't fully understand JEE while starting out. It's not impossible, but it will be quite a challenge that might end in you saying JEE is bad for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Simon - good point, and also the OP's organization should invest in some training.  Ideally they should start with a smallish pilot project that can be written off if it is a failure.

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable with Java EE you shouldn't adopt it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I think I'll try to get some training arranged. The pet store suggestion did lead to me discover that Sun also have something called "Project SocialSite" (https://socialsite.dev.java.net/) which is a little out of date but does demonstrate a real application using the Glassfish server and some Java EE features.

Comment: Everything can be done without Eclipse or Maven or other Java tools. You just need to talk to people who have experience of Java & also other languages. I have seen that many guys who have experience with nothing except Java don't really get using other editors, other build systems. They assume you will be programming, compiling  and everything else using systems very similar to what they use.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation a few years ago. I was a C programmer using vi and pico on Linux, and I got hired onto a J2EE project. They may be slightly dated references and there are some differences in the newer versions, but I used the books Developing Web Services with Apache Axis and J2EE 1.4: The Big Picture as great jumping off points for me and the team I was working with. I highly recommend each book. Also check out [Sun/Oracle's J2EE tutorial online](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/). Your first iteration won't be production quality code, and should be considered a throwaway from the start, but it will get you off the ground with an IDE and the J2EE framework.